# What does 'this' represent in the javascript below?

Tags: javascript, call, this

(Sorry, another `this` question in javascript.)

I have the code below, and I'm wondering what 'this' represents in the call at the end-- the Window or the Bird?

```
var Bird = (function () {
    Bird.name = 'Bird';

    function Bird(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Bird.prototype.move = function (feet) {
        return alert(this.name + (" flew" + feet + "ft."));
    };

    return Bird;

}).call(this);
```

Comment: I tested this in an otherwise empty script by adding a parameter x to the function and an alert(x) inside the call -- it's **undefined**.

Comment: @goldilocks It doesn't work that way.  When you use `call`, the first argument is the context/scope you are executing in, it does not get passed as the parameter to the function.  To test what you are suggesting correctly, one would try `(function(){ console.log(this); }).call(this);`.  If you want to see the argument, try `(function(arg){ console.log(this, arg); }).call(this, this);`.  Both of these tests show that 'this' is `window`.

Comment: jsFiddle of my example: http://jsfiddle.net/Umseu/1

Comment: Matt: Ah, that makes sense -- I tried `call(this, "okay")` and "okay" is the first param to the anon function that defines Bird. Using "this, this", it is the window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, assuming there is no parent scope, it is `window`

EDIT: See example: http://jsfiddle.net/Umseu/1

Comment: Thanks Matt.  BTW, do you have suggestions on how to paste code in a posting so the formatting holds?  I noticed you changed mine some-- which is fine, but when I pasted it in the indents were all screwed up and I had to use spaces to get them working properly.

Comment: @larryq If you are copying from an editor, perhaps it is an issue of using tabs (\t) instead of spaces for indent? Not sure.  For quick cleanup of JS, I just head over to http://jsbeautifier.org/, which is what I did for yours

Answer (score 5):

Probably `window`, because it's not in any particular context that would give `this` any special meaning.

Answer (score 3):

The window. `.call(this)` is not written inside the bird. It simply calls an anonymous function that happen to return "Bird" "constructor".

Answer (score 1):

Call `console.log(this)` at first line in the anonymous function. That return the scope, `window`.

Comment: Inside what function? There's three functions in the code - and some of them will actually refer to the Bird. Calling console.log(this); after the code above will tell the answer.